# Customize the page block buttons in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, html5, pageblock, pageblocksection

I am developing an edit page for my company and i have a problem with the page buttons. Is it possible to put them in a random position not just the one offered with the location="top/bottom/both".

As you can see on the image i have buttons that point out to the right section in the pageblock but the buttons are only showing in the Sales section. I want them to be seen only in the confirm part at the end of the inserting wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put the page block buttons in a div tag as follows:

```
<div style="margin-left: 123456px">             
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom"  >
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" immediate="true"/>                                
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</div>
```

This will help you place the save/cancel buttons left or right in the page block.